# Cannot connect to Mac after VS Update to 17.7.3

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I just installed the new Visual Studio 2022 Update 17.7.3 on my Windows PC.
Since then, I cannot pair with my Mac anymore to deploy my .NET MAUI App. I am getting the following Error Message:

*Could not install workload 'ios'. Details: Error during workload installation: Error installing the manifest "microsoft.net.sdk.ios" in version 16.4.7098: The file "microsoft.net.sdk.ios.manifest-7.0.100::16.4.7098" was not found in NuGet feeds "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json;[https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting IOS through MAUI, I would certainly avoid 17.7.3. After a day of messing around, I had to restore the whole PC from a backup as the .Net 7 had got corrupted somewhere along the line of downgrading Visual Studio, so that none of the projects loaded at all.

I like VS and have used it since the early days of v1.5! However, I wish they wouldn't put out releases with half-baked features that ultimately cause what worked yesterday to stop today. Productivity should be focussed on the apps., not testing environment updates and reporting them on GitHub every 5 minutes. I feel like a beta tester, as I suspect do many others.

Sorry to moan! My advice is to avoid 17.7.3 altogether if you want iOS to work.

Comment: Absolutely agree with what you say and feel the same way. Especially Bug reporting got a subject for me and makes it really a problem to get them a minimal reproducible example of the problem. It’s like I need to do the work for them and find the root cause already, otherwise the Bug report gets closed anyway. But when you look at Bug reports on GitHub, you hope that the next VS Update fixes parts of it. Unfortunately, I often had the situation that my app was not working anymore and I had to spend a lot of time to get it back to working.

Answer (score 2):

For the ones having the messed manifests (not fixed by the VS downgrade nor repair action from the VS Installer):

- Download the workload manifests from [nuget.org](https://nuget.org), e.g. for `7.0.100`:

  - [MAUI](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Maui.Manifest-7.0.100/7.0.92)
  - [macOS](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.macOS.Manifest-7.0.100/13.3.7090)
  - [iOS](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.iOS.Manifest-7.0.100/16.4.7090)
- Replace the content in `c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100\<workload>` by the content from nuget `<workload>.manifest-7.0.100.<version>.nupkg\data`.

Answer (score 1):

Who does not have the opportunity to roll back the version, do

- Open C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.ios\WorkloadManifest.json as administrator
- Edit all version fields from "16.4.7098" to "16.4.7090".
- At the expense of running the "dotnet restore" command in the project, I didn't need it, but if it didn't work after the first two steps, try

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues around this, but doing this little ritual always seem to work.

- Make sure Visual Studio is up to date on the MAC
- Make sure the MAC is up to date
- Make sure XCode is up to date
- Restart the mac
- Start Visual Studio
- If not working, go through the setting for remote login.

If not installed [XCodes](https://github.com/XcodesOrg/XcodesApp) with an s, consider it.

**Update**

There is an Issue with 17.7.3 and a rollback to 17.7.2 is the workaround at the time being.
[image]

Comment: I did an Update of VS on the Mac which showed an Error Box in the End. Opening up the Updates on the Mac again did not show Updates anymore. So, I guess they should be installed. But, still no success in pairing.

Comment: Rollback to 17.7.0 didn't help to me. The dotnet manifests are still messed by the *.7098 versions. So I'm even unable to install the workloads manually. Very pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

- Downgrade Visual Studio to 17.7.2.
- According to the above post, download the workload manifests from nuget.org.
- Replace the content in c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100<workload> by the content from nuget .manifest-7.0.100..nupkg\data.
- Then run dotnet workload restore command, e.g.:

```
dotnet workload restore C:\Projects\MauiApp\MauiApp.csproj
```

Comment: What I am asking myself, why do they have non working elements in their update which are not working in the end and which is then not corrected? The easiest thing could be they upload this part to nuget.org?